# tkinter: How can I use one vertical scroll bar to scroll two canvases?

Tags: python, tkinter

In my UI I need two canvases, each with their own horizontal scroll bar, but with a single scroll bar controlling the vertical movement of both canvases.

The following code creates two canvases, each with their own horizontal and vertical scrollbars. How can I get rid of one of the vertical scrollbars? Apologies for the length of code, it's as canonical as I could make it.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class MainUI:
    def __init__(self, root):

        mainframe = Frame(root)
        mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))

        # set up the first canvas, with large red triangle
        canvas1 = Canvas(mainframe, background="turquoise")
        canvas1.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(N,S,W,E))

        canvas1_hscroller = Scrollbar(mainframe, orient="horizontal",command=canvas1.xview)
        canvas1_hscroller.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=(W,E))
        canvas1.configure(xscrollcommand=canvas1_hscroller.set)

        canvas1_vscroller = Scrollbar(mainframe, orient="vertical",command=canvas1.yview)
        canvas1_vscroller.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(N,S))
        canvas1.configure(yscrollcommand=canvas1_vscroller.set)

        points = [0,0,1000,800,800,1000]
        triangle = canvas1.create_polygon(points,fill="red")

        canvas1.configure(scrollregion=canvas1.bbox("all"))

        # set up the second canvas, with large green triangle
        canvas2 = Canvas(mainframe, background="orange")
        canvas2.grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=(N,S,W,E))

        canvas2_hscroller = Scrollbar(mainframe, orient="horizontal",command=canvas2.xview)
        canvas2_hscroller.grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=(W,E))
        canvas2.configure(xscrollcommand=canvas2_hscroller.set)

        canvas2_vscroller = Scrollbar(mainframe, orient="vertical",command=canvas2.yview)
        canvas2_vscroller.grid(column=4, row=1, sticky=(N,S))
        canvas2.configure(yscrollcommand=canvas2_vscroller.set)

        points = [0,0,1000,800,800,1000]
        triangle = canvas2.create_polygon(points,fill="green")

        canvas2.configure(scrollregion=canvas2.bbox("all"))

root = Tk()
ui = MainUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you want them to scroll separately? Will both of the Canvas have different scroll region? If any of that, you just need to refer in the scrollcommand to the scrollbar you want to use. It's not clear to me why do you need our help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make the canvases attributes of the instance:

```py
...
self.canvas1 = Canvas(mainframe, background="turquoise")
...
self.canvas2 = Canvas(mainframe, background="orange")
```

and use the `self.` prefix everywhere where you reference previously `canvas1` and `canvas2`

Then define a new method

```py
def v_scroll(self, *args):
    self.canvas1.yview(*args)
    self.canvas2.yview(*args)
```

Then just set the scrollbar `command` to that method:

```py
canvas_vscroller = Scrollbar(..., command=self.v_scroll)
```

Additionally, don't use `from tkinter import *`, it is bad practice to use `*` when importing modules. Import only what you need. For example in this case

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Canvas, Scrollbar
```

Complete example (using `import tkinter as tk` which is even better):

```py
import tkinter as tk


class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # set up the first canvas, with large red triangle
        self.canvas1 = tk.Canvas(self, background="turquoise")
        self.canvas1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='news')

        self.canvas1_hscroller = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas1.xview)
        self.canvas1_hscroller.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='we')
        self.canvas1.configure(xscrollcommand=self.canvas1_hscroller.set)

        points = [0, 0, 1000, 800, 800, 1000]
        self.canvas1.create_polygon(points, fill="red")

        self.canvas1.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas1.bbox("all"))

        # set up the second canvas, with large green triangle
        self.canvas2 = tk.Canvas(self, background="orange")
        self.canvas2.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='news')

        self.canvas2_hscroller = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas2.xview)
        self.canvas2_hscroller.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='we')
        self.canvas2.configure(xscrollcommand=self.canvas2_hscroller.set)

        points = [0, 0, 1000, 800, 800, 1000]
        self.canvas2.create_polygon(points, fill="green")

        self.canvas2.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas2.bbox("all"))

        self.v_scroller = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.v_scroll)
        self.v_scroller.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky='ns')
        self.canvas1.config(yscrollcommand=self.v_scroller.set)

    def v_scroll(self, *args):
        self.canvas1.yview(*args)
        self.canvas2.yview(*args)


root = MainWindow()
root.mainloop()
```

And btw, rows and columns start from `0`, so first row and column would be `row=0`, `column=0` accordingly

Comment: Mattiiss, very many thanks for your detailed and informative answer. It was a problem I'd been struggling with for some time.

Comment: @JonathanAllin glad to help also if you want to please see [What to do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), this will help future readers and also allow to mark other questions as duplicates. Thank you!

Comment: @JonathanAllin also I forgot and now have updated the answer, but one of the canvases had to have a `yscrollcomand=self.v_scroller.set` so that the slider would stay where it was scrolled, a minor detail

Comment: Hello Mattiiss, last night I spotted the problem you mention above. Not minor!

Unfortunately I can't get your proposal to work. Did you mean `v_scroll` or `v_scroller`? I presume I need something like `self.canvas1.configure(yscrollcomand=self.v_scroll.set)`, but this complains because I `v_scroll` has no `set` method.

With thanks.

Comment: @JonathanAllin definitely meant `self.v_scroller.set` as that is the scrollbar, the other is a method. It should work as is in the answer, in case you missed, I had updated the answer with the solution

Comment: Hello Matisss. You are of course correct. Independently I realised the problem was that I'd defined v_scroller *after* I'd try to use it in the configure command. Doh!

Comment: An unrelated problem I'm trying to resolve: around the canvases is a grey (or probably white) border. Can I get rid of this? In particular I want the two canvases to butt up seamlessly. Thanks

Comment: Answering my own question, from an Internet search setting `highlightthickness=0` is a good start.